# Ajax append array data individually

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have array of data returning by Ajax and I want to show them one by one in panel, currently they are all in one panel at the same time, I wish to have multiple step of this data.

## Code

`HTML`

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="answerPanel"></div>
</div>
```

`Script`

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'{{url('dashboard/getQuizzes')}}/'+projectId,
    beforeSend: function(data) {
        console.log("click - ajax before send", data);
    },
    success:function(data){
        $(data.quizzes).each(function(_, i){
            $('.answerPanel').append(i.question);
        });
    }
});
```

this `$('.answerPanel').append(i.question);` is returning all data together in my view, I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51028976/8490993) the only difference was it had brake line with it :)

#### Result

[image: one]

### Question

My question is how can I make multi step panel with this data?

> What I'm looking for is having `how are you?fg` (*based on my screenshot*) in first page then I click next button and get `uid` and so on...

*I'm aware this question might seem silly but please try to help before giving down vote :)*

Comment: so first it should load how are you?fg and there is a next button when you click on it only the uid should resolve and added as the next line like wise you need to get it. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Make a global variable say var quizzes = []; Then on ajax success assign  quizzes  = data.quizzes. And on a button click fetch one by one and append on your element.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS exactly

Comment: @Ajith where should i make that global variable? would you mind sharing an answer please?

Comment: '{{url('dashboard/getQuizzes')}}/'+projectId this gives all the response as list or it loads one at a time like how are you?fg have project id as 1 and uid is having project id as 2

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS that url is returning all quizzes based on the `projectId` this is how my data look like https://ibb.co/C6ytCJL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body  id="banner">
<ul id="eventCal">
</ul>
<button id="clicks">Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 var quizzes = [{title:'title1',choices:[{title:'choice1'},{title:'choice2'}]},
       {title:'title2',choices:[{title:'new1'},{title:'new2'}]},
       {title:'title3',choices:[{title:'demo1'},{title:'demo2'}]}];
 var index   = 0;
 console.log(quizzes.length)
 $("#clicks").click(function(){
  if(typeof  quizzes[index] != 'undefined'){
   var html = '<li><span>'+quizzes[index].title+'</span></li>';
   if(quizzes[index].choices.length > 0){
   html+='<li class="choises">';
   quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    //console.log(element.title); 
    html+='<ul>';
    html+='<li><span>'+element.title+'</span></li>';
    html+='</ul>';
   });
   html+='</li>';
   }
   
   
   $("#eventCal").html(html);
   index++;
  }
  if(quizzes.length === index)
   $("#clicks").html("Finish");
  
 })
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: oh you were using id instead of class :)

Comment: ok it returns one by one but still in same panel, i need to remove old data when i click next button.

Comment: Then do html instead of append, Modified in the code now

Comment: ok that works, is there possible way to change button text when all object are finished?

Comment: @mafortis Can you check now

Comment: may i ask you one additional question?  How do I get each `data.quizzes` child arrays? you see this is my data structure https://ibb.co/C6ytCJL each of this `data.quizzes` have an array of answers which i will need to show so user can select.

Comment: @mafortis Your format is not fully visible in your given link

Comment: i make new screenshot

Comment: here you go this is from network response  https://ibb.co/sWNpmyZ

Comment: this is what it will be in case you need logic as well  https://ibb.co/MsyWDzB

Comment: made new question might be cleaner with my full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59659932/how-to-get-child-arrays-in-ajax-html

Comment: @mafortis I have added answer in your new thread, Please upvote and accept . Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think iterator is exactly what you looking for. It is simple yet so elegant and powerfull:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 id="question"></h3>
<div id="answers"></div>
<button id="nextBtn">Next question</button>

<script>

  // Iterator
  function iterator(array) {
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
      next: function() {
        return nextIndex < array.length
          ? { value: array[nextIndex++], done: false }
          : { done: true };
      }
    };
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
  
    var quizzesArray = [
      {
        question: 'How are you?',
        choices: [
          { choice: 'Okay' },
          { choice: 'Bad' },
          { choice: 'Who cares?' }
        ]
      },
      {
        question: 'What time is it now?',
        choices: [{ choice: '4pm' }, { choice: '2am' }, { choice: 'No idea' }]
      },
      {
        question: 'What is your job?',
        choices: [
          { choice: 'Student' },
          { choice: 'Teacher' },
          { choice: 'Unemployed' }
        ]
      },
      {
        question: 'Why are you angry?',
        choices: [
          { choice: 'I am hungry' },
          { choice: 'I lost my dog' },
          { choice: 'Not angry' }
        ]
      }
    ];

    // Initialize the iterator
    var quiz = iterator(quizzesArray);

    $('#nextBtn').click(function() {
      var upNext = quiz.next();

      if (upNext.done) {
        return;
      }

      var current = upNext.value;
      var answers = '';

      current.choices.forEach(function(choice) {
        answers += `
          <p>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="${choice.choice}">
            <label>${choice.choice}</label>
          </p>
        `;
      });

      $('#question').text(current.question);
      $('#answers').html(answers);
      
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: and then how do i loop my child arrays in this? each `quizzesArray` has array inside of it as answers so later user can select those answers.

Comment: So, it is like a multiple choice test, you want to print one question and also 3-4 possible answers. Did I get you right?

Comment: these might help  https://ibb.co/sWNpmyZ and https://ibb.co/MsyWDzB

Comment: made new question might be cleaner with my full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59659932/how-to-get-child-arrays-in-ajax-html

Comment: You can use same iterator function. I have edited my answer, feel free check it out.